# If the final chunk of a chunked array can't be split evenly then add empty strings into the final chunk

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this problem where I want to split an array of elements into equal chunks of three. But if the final chunk can't be split evenly then add empty strings.

I am using lodash _.chunk method but not sure how to add extra empty strings in the final chunk.

```
// I will get unknown number elements in the array.

const arr1 = [{elem1}, {elem2}, {elem3}, {elem4}]
// above array does have 4 elements. If I use _.chunk I will get something like [[{elem1},{elem2},{elem3}], [{elem4}]]
// I am looking to get something like [[{}, {}, {}], [{}, '', '']].
```

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this in JS?

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to increase the `array` length until it get a divisible length by **3** after that you could slice the array simply using `slice` method like this

```js
let arr = [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}];

function split(arr){
   let res = [];
   
   while(arr.length % 3 != 0){
      arr.push({foo: 'bar'});      
   }
       
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    res.push(arr.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + (arr.length / 3)))
   
   return res;
}

console.log(split(arr));
```

Comment: OP wants to get groups of 3 not 2

Comment: @Reyno check the answer again

Comment: Clever solution. Only thing remaining is he asked to fill with 'empty string'. `{foo: 'bar'}` could be {foo: ''}

Comment: just change this line to what you want to be inserted `arr.push({foo: 'bar'});`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why everyone is rewriting `chunk`. Do the chunking with lodash's `_.chunk` like you are, then just fill in the last chunk.

```js
let chunkedArray = [
  [{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'}],
  [{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'},{foo:'bar'}],
  [{foo:'bar'}],
];
const chunkSize = 3;
const filler = '';
// fill in
// Create a new array, 
chunkedArray = [
  // with all of the chunks except the last one
  ...chunkedArray.slice(0,-1), 
  // Add the last chunk
  [
    // with all of its contents
    ...chunkedArray[chunkedArray.length - 1], 
    // plus the contents of a new array, the length of a chunk minus the length
    // of the last chunk, filled with an empty string (or whatever)
    ...new Array(chunkSize - chunkedArray[chunkedArray.length - 1].length).fill(filler)
  ]
];
// now chunkedArray is complete, all arrays the same size
console.log(chunkedArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console { height: 100%; }
```